# How do I make a div fly off the screen on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so i've got this round div.

```
<div id = "dot"></div>
```

With this styling, it flies off the screen when you hover over it.

```
#dot {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;
  transition: all 2s;
}

#dot:hover {
  top: -1000vh;
}

#dot {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

I want the fly-off-the-screen transition to occur when the dot is clicked, and I'm looking for a solution that is pure CSS or vanilla javascript. If it's of any significance, the dot is ultimately gonna be wrapped in an a link element, and its dramatic exit will herald the load of a new page.

Bonus question: if this round div eventually has an SVG in it, will that negatively affect its performance/appearance?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by adding a `tabindex` to your `div` and changing your CSS from `:hover` to `:focus`.

(Don't forget to remove the outline).

```css
#dot {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;
  transition: all 2s;
}

#dot:focus {
  top: -1000vh;
  outline: none;
}

#dot {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div  tabindex='1' id = "dot"></div>
```

Comment: Why does it need a `tabindex`?

Comment: Div, span, table, etc are not focusable by default, but can receive focus if tabindex is applied. There might be other ways doing that with pure CSS. But that's all that I've got ;)

Comment: `<button id="dot"><span class="visually-hidden">I have a purpose, let's explain it to screen reader users</span></button>` would receive focus without the need of tabindex and will behave as expected for keyboard users

Comment: You are correct. I was using OP's original HTML and modified accordingly assuming that's what he wants.

Comment: Phenomenal! This works perfectly, but do you know what parameter causes the dot eventually coming back?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to set the timing on the "in" differently than the "out". The ease-in option is the timing function. Other options are default, linear, ease-out, ease-in-out, and cubic-bezier.  There isn't any information on setting the transition-in to zero seconds, unfortunately.  An alternate option might be to use JS to get the functionality you want and still use the CSS animation.